# hair particle with object

Tags: particles, hair

[image]
[image]

hello, I am testing particle hair, And I want to bend mesh along the hair Path,
How could I change the softness of the hair??
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

hello

I could bend mesh along hair with particle instancer,
duplicate a mesh which is used as hair object, and add modifier "particle instancer"
and choose the object which has particle system as Object. It worked like the picture.